# Why $5n^{12}+25456n^8+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{23}n^2$ is in $o(n^{157/12})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I'm reading a course about the Landau notation, And one example is given, but there is something I don't understand.

***Below the excerpt from this course***

> Let $P$ a polynomial function of degree $p$, with real coefficients,
>   then  $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \qquad \alpha>p\implies (P(n))_{n\in
>  \mathbb{N}}\in o(n^{\alpha})$
>
> Then this example is given
>
> $\left(5n^{12}+25456n^8+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{23}n^2 \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in o(n^{\frac{157}{12}})$

My question is why not 
$\left(5n^{12}+25456n^8+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{23}n^2 \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in o(n^{13})$  ??

Even if $\dfrac{157}{12}>13$,is there something subtle, I haven't understood?

Comment: $5n^{12}+\cdots$ is $O(n^{12})$ and therefore $o(n^{12+\epsilon})$ for any positive value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: There's nothing subtler. It's just because $157/12>12$.

Comment: Also, the first portion of the excerpt is a bit poorly formulated, since it uses the symbol $n$ for two different purposes.

Comment: 157/12 >12 I agree, but 145/12 is a better example, isn't it?

Comment: @Stu, yes, it would be a better example.  But maybe the fact that it's caused you to think about things makes the $157/12$ a good example!

Comment: @Barry Cipra : Yes it's right, it's a course downloaded from internet. I will correct the message.